# SQL Server Log Shipping from 2012 to 2014/2016

Tags: sql-server

I am being told that it is NOT possible to do Log Shipping from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2014 or 2016. Is this correct?

If not, are there any caveats to the process when Log Shipping to a SQL Server version higher than the source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can happily do ONE-WAY logshipping from lower version to higher version.

The only caveat is that once you failover to higher version, you cannot failback to lower version... same applies to Database Mirroring.

This technique is normally used when you want to do migration from lower version to higher version with minimal downtime.

Comment: Didn't see I made a duplicate answer. Deleted mine, upvoted yours :)

Comment: Note, though, that you can't read from the secondary if it's on a later version.

Comment: Another note is that when you recover the database, if it's very large, you'll have to wait for the upgrade process to complete before it comes online which could take a while on larger databases.  So if you're doing this for a migration then factor that time to complete the upgrade process into your recovery time.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft that must be why I am being informed that this is not possible.   We want to be able to read the data after a restore of log files.